# Visual Studio (C) ignoring escape sequences

Tags: c, text

Going through Kernighan, and I am coding on visual studio with windows. Why doesn't the following program doesn't pick up tab characters, new lines, or spaces? I have to manually type its associated integer. Here's the word count program:

```
#define IN 1 /*State of being inside word*/
#define OUT 0 /*State of being outside word*/

countWords() {
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = (nw = (nc = 0));
    while ((c = getchar() != EOF)) {
        nc++;
        if (c == '\n') {
            nl++;
        }
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
        }
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            nw++;
        }
        printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
    }
}
```

My test input was 'one two three' and the output was '0 1 14'. Indicating that it didn't recognise  space character ' '. Is there a setting on VS that needs to be changed to get this working?

Comment: OT: it should be `void countWords()`. `countWords()` is equivalent to `int countWords()`. If you declarfe a function or a variable without a type, the type is implicitly `int`. Don't use this ever, it's deprecated and usually your compiler should give a warning for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with operator precedence.

```
while ((c = getchar() != EOF)) {
```

The `c` variable gets the boolean value of the expression `getchar() != EOF`. It doesn't hold the character that was read in like you are probably expecting.

You probably meant to write it as:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```